# Are unit tests executing within Visual Studio or on TFS server?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

How I can detect in code if my MS Test unit tests are executing within Visual Studio or as part of a build running within the TFS server?

One example of why I want to do this is that I have some integration tests that restore and upgrade a database, when running in VS I just want to skip this step and just use the most recent database. There are also lots of settings and file locations that want to change when running as a dev in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK done it by just checking whether the computer name is the hard-coded name of the TFS server! Feels a bit hacky but it works for now....